# Javascript chunk path has colons https://example.com/js/chunk-vendors.b3792e11.js:18:16400

Tags: javascript, apache, vue.js, npm

I have build a Vue application with npm run build and uploaded the dist folder to Apache server.

Apache isn't able to find the file when this part is there (:18:16400) which is being requested from the app.

what is causing this issue ?
should it be solved from npm or from the web server ?

Comment: That looks like line and column numbers. What's the exact error message?

Comment: the browser stops working and ask if to stop the script and 
the logs shows warning about the script says timeout 
https://example.com/js/chunk-vendors.b3792e11.js:18:16400

Comment: Yeah ok, if it says there's a timeout it doesn't mean that it can't load the file. It means that while executing the script it timed out at that point (line 18, column 16400). Nothing to do with Apache or loading the file.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that there was an infinite loop which tells about the timeout issue.
Vue seems to stops the infinite loop in development but it remains there in build for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was an infinite loop which tells about the timeout issue. Vue seems to stops the infinite loop in development but it remains there in build for production